# Querying a hash/bson document field in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hi there I have a Mongoid model, Spec, with mongoid-history gem added to it like this:

```
class Spec
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::History::Trackable
  field :due_at, type: DateTime

  track_history on: [:due_at],
                :modifier_field => :modifier, # adds "referenced_in :modifier" to track who made the change, default is :modifier
                :version_field => :version,   # adds "field :version, :type => Integer" to track current version, default is :version
                :track_create   =>  false,    # track document creation, default is false
                :track_update   =>  true,     # track document updates, default is true
                :track_destroy  =>  false     # track document destruction, default is false

end

spec = Spec.first
hist = spec.history_tracks.first 
#=> { id: 123, modified: {due_at: 2017-06-12}, ... }

hist.modified.class 
#=> BSON::Document
```

My question is, how can we query the `modified` field by the existence of its `due_at` field? A failed attempt looked like this:

```
spec.history_tracks.where(:'modified.due_at.exists' => true)
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
spec.history_tracks.not.where('modified.due_at' => nil)
```